# ¿Como puedo validar si un carácter es numero o no en PSEint?

Tags: validación, pseint, pseudocódigo, numero

tengo este pseudocodigo en pseint y la idea es validar si un texto tiene 2 numeros, pero cuando hago la validacion en la `linea 8` pues me revienta, por que no puede validar un caracter como numero ¿como podria verificar que una letra sea numero o caracter?

```
1 Algoritmo palabra
2    Leer palabra
3    num <- 0
4
5    Para i <- 1 Hasta Longitud(palabra)
6      char <- Subcadena(palabra,i,i)
7      Para j <- 0 Hasta  n        
8        Si ConvertirANumero(char) == j Entonces
9           num = num + 1
10       Fin Si
11     Fin Para
12   Fin Para
13
14   Si num > 2 Entonces
15      escribir "Contiene numeros"
16   SiNo
17      escribir "Le faltan numeros"
18   Fin Si
19 FinAlgoritmo
```

Comment: utiliza el or lógico y compara si es algún número pero trata el dígito como un carácter

Answer (score 0):

Buenas noches mira sí te sirve este Pseudocódigo:

```
Algoritmo validarTexto
    Definir palabra, char Como Caracter
    Definir num Como Entero
    Escribir "Escriba una palabra "
    Leer palabra
    num <- 0
    Para i <- 1 Hasta Longitud(palabra)
        char <- Subcadena(char,i,i)
        Para j <- 0 Hasta  n
            Si ConvertirANumero(char) == j Entonces
                num = num + 1
            Fin Si
        Fin Para
        Fin Para
        Si num > 1 Entonces
        escribir "La palabra ", palabra, " contiene: ", num, " letras"
        SiNo
        escribir "Por favor escriba más de una letra"
        Fin Si
FinAlgoritmo
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.